# Why do we need IP header checksum when CRC is already present at Data Link level?

Tags: networking, ip, data-link-layer

If there is any corruption in the IP header then it will be detected by CRC at data link level of the next immediate router and the frame will be discarded. Why do we need the IP header checksum at all?

Comment: IP makes no assumptions about the data link layer, which does not have to be Ethernet, and does not have to have a CRC. Off topic.

Comment: Just remember that IPv4 was an experiment that escaped the lab, and it was being developed on unreliable links in the absence of modern data-link protocols. Its replacement, IPv6, has eliminated the header checksum because it improves upon IPv4 using lessons learned, removing features of IPv4 that do not work well and adding features not found in IPv4.

Comment: Thankyou guys. Got it. Gonna take this question down now.